# read jms message from queue using selector

Tags: java, jms, ems

I have a client in java which send a jms message in a queue ("queue-request"). The message contains a int property ("id") containing the unique client id number. The message is being processed and than lands in another queue ("queue-respond"). How can let the client wait till the message with his id is in the queue and then read it out.
I have tried to use a listener and implement the onMessage but how can I then stop listening when the message is received?

Answer (score 1):

JMS synchronous can be acchived using JMSReplyTo .
Create Temp Queue while sending orginal Message with the same session.
Start Listen the Temp Queue and set the Original Message JMSReplyTo the TmpQueue.

Use TempQueue Receiver.receive() to make the thread wait ( synchronous)

Complete sample code can be found in

http://jmsexample.zcage.com/

Comment: and how would this solution look without temporary queues but just one which all the client are listening to?

Comment: so what i am looking for is how to asynchronously pull a message destined for the client from one big queue. But this works perfectly for synchronous messaging. voted up for win

Comment: JMS designed especially for Asyc , it doesn’t provide sync as inbuilt feature. You can achieve sycn with help  of JMSReplyTo. If you use the destination as Queue which is listened by n number of client then the message will not be delivered all the Queue Listener. So you have to use only "topic" as destination for JMSReplyTo. And in client use subscriber to receive the message and verify the ID.
Some thing like
While(true){
 Message message = .. receive Message from topic using .receive()
If message.getText().equals(id){
 Break;
}
}

Answer (score 0):

In JMS you need to specify the listener for the queue so that if the message is sent, then the particular listener is selected to receive the message. In Spring you can specify the listener in the bean configuration file, as an example:

```
<bean id="myListener" class="mypackage.MyMessageListener" />

<bean id="queueBean" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic">
    <constructor-arg value="Queue-Request"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactoryBean" />
    <property name="destination" ref="queueBean" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="myListener" />
</bean>
```

Then you can write the class `MyMessageListener` to implement the `MessageListener` interface:

```
public class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener {
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        //handle message here ...
    }   
}
```

This will ensure that `MyMessageListener` will get the message sent from the queue. Note that Queue is p2p, so if the message is received by `MyMessageListener`, it will not be received by other listeners which don't subscribe to this queue.